# R - subset rows by rows in another data frame

Tags: r, subset

Let's say I have a data frame `df` containing only factors/categorical variables. I have another data frame `conditions` where each row contains a different combination of the different factor levels of some subset of variables in `df` (made using `expand.grid` and `levels` etc.). I'm trying to figure out a way of subsetting `df` based on each row of `conditions`. So for example, if the column names of `conditions` are `c("A", "B", "C")` and the first row is `c('a1', 'b1', 'c1')`, then I want `df[df$A == 'a1' & df$B == 'b1' & df$C == 'c1',]`, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think this is a great time to use `merge` (or `dplyr::*_join` or ...):

```r
df1 <- expand.grid(A = letters[1:4], B = LETTERS[1:4], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1$rn <- seq_len(nrow(df1))

# 'df2' contains the conditions we want to filter (retain)
df2 <- data.frame(
  a1 = c('a', 'a', 'c'),
  b1 = c('B', 'C', 'C'),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df1
#    A B rn
# 1  a A  1
# 2  b A  2
# 3  c A  3
# 4  d A  4
# 5  a B  5
# 6  b B  6
# 7  c B  7
# 8  d B  8
# 9  a C  9
# 10 b C 10
# 11 c C 11
# 12 d C 12
# 13 a D 13
# 14 b D 14
# 15 c D 15
# 16 d D 16

df2
#   a1 b1
# 1  a  B
# 2  a  C
# 3  c  C
```

Using `df2` to define which combinations we need to keep,

```r
merge(df1, df2, by.x=c('A','B'), by.y=c('a1','b1'))
#   A B rn
# 1 a B  5
# 2 a C  9
# 3 c C 11

# or
dplyr::inner_join(df1, df2, by=c(A='a1', B='b1'))
```

(I defined `df2` with different column names just to show how it works, but in reality since its purpose is "solely" to be declarative on which combinations to filter, it would make sense to me to have the same column names, in which case the `by=` argument just gets simpler.)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create the condition with `Reduce`

```
df[Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, df[c("A", "B", "C")], df[1, c("A", "B", "C")])),]
```

Or another option is `rowSums`

```
df[rowSums(df[c("A", "B", "C")] == 
           df[1, c("A", "B", "C")][col(df[c("A", "B", "C")])]) == 3,]
```